# Using array_filter() with a callback that returns an array

Tags: php, arrays, explode, array-filter

I have data like this:

```
a|b|c|d|e|f|g
h|i|j|k|l|m|n
o|p|q|r|s|t|u
```

I can easily use `explode("\n", $data)` to get an array of all the lines (this is a ~4.0GB file), but now I want to make it a multi-dimensional array by using `explode()` based on the vertical pipe. Here is what I tried:

```
$data = explode("\n", './path-to-file.txt');
$results = array_filter($data, function ($el) {
   return explode('|', $el);
});
```

However, this results in a single-dimensional array with the original line in string form.

How can I use `array_filter()` with a callback that happens to return an array?

Edit: I *could* use `foreach($data as $datum)` and do the `explode()` that way, but when I tried that, I utilized about four times the amount of RAM than the size of the file, and that is not desirable. This seems like a perfect opportunity to use a callback function, but I seemingly cannot do that with `array_filter()`.

Comment: I think use array_map instead

Comment: What are you doing with the array? Can the file be processed one line at a time instead of reading it all into memory, or do you need to sort it or something?

Comment: It's not the method of getting the file data into an array that's using so much more memory than the file size. It's the actual array itself: https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_filter()` filters elements to include or exclude them and expects `true` to include the element or `false` to exclude.  Use `array_map()`:

```
$data = explode("\n", './path-to-file.txt');
$results = array_map(function ($el) {
   return explode('|', $el);
}, $data);
```

A more memory efficient way would be to read line by line:

```
if(($handle = fopen("./path-to-file.txt", "r")) !== false) {
    while(($results[] = fgetcsv($handle, 0, "|")) !== false) {}
}
```

Comment: I utilized ~34GB of memory when I do it this way. Is there no "cheaper" way to do this?

Comment: Added another way.

Comment: `fgetcsv()` is significantly slower than even doing the `foreach()` by hand, and uses a similar amount of RAM. In fact, this script has been executing for 11 minutes, and still uses a tremendous amount of memory compared to the size of the actual file. However, `array_map()` was the answer to the question, so thanks!

Comment: What are you doing inside the while of the `fgetcsv()`, solution? The solution itself doesn't use much memory at all, unless you're just building a giant 2d array in memory, in which case you'll never escape the memory trap unless you rework what you're doing with the data

Comment: Correct, the second approach will only read in one line at a time, but the `$results` array will grow quite large.